# unwanted string prepended while reading cookie in client side

Tags: php, jquery, json, cookies

I am trying to create cookie which contains credentials encrypted on the client side, currently am just storing an array in json format using set cookie function in php. but when i read back the cookie its not same as what i set.
setting cookie using setcookie function in server.

```
    $credential = array();
    $credential['id'] = $result[0]['id'];
    $credential['username'] = $_POST['_username'];
    $credential['password'] = $_POST['_password'];
    $credential['auth'] = TRUE;

    $_SESSION['id'] = $credential['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $credential['username'];
    $_SESSION['passsword'] = $credential['password'];
    $_SESSION['auth'] = TRUE;

    $this->setcookie("cr", $this->encode($credential));

function setcookie($name, $value) {
    $cookiedata = $value;
    return setcookie($name, serialize($cookiedata), time()+3600*24*1000, '/');
  }
```

in Client side tried following method but none of resulted in clean cookie

```
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($.cookie('cr'))));
      console.log(JSON.stringify($.cookie('cr')));
```

both resulted in

> s:62:"{"id":"6","username":"yashwanth","password":"asd","auth":true}";

expected

> {"id":"6","username":"yashwanth","password":"asd","auth":true};

Comment: Show the `encode` method too please.

Comment: updated my query check out

Comment: `serialize` is not compatible with json.